# Extract next to last line from single cell Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a file where I'm trying to take the values of a single cell and make outputs based on that single cell value. I have found ways to extract the first, second, and last lines of the cell, but unfortunately I don't understand enough of the formulas I'm looking at to be able to get the nest to last line.

How do I extract the next to last line of data from a single cell in Excel, and is there a formula I don't know which can easily be adapted to extract any line (assuming you understand the forumla)? Can you please explain the forumla in your answer.

Here is what I'm working with presently:

**Cell Value**

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

**Formulas for Extracting Line 1, 2, and Last (in order)**

`=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(E2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(E2,CHAR(10),CHAR(1),2))-1)),"$a"&LEFT(E2,FIND(CHAR(10),E2)-1),"$a"&LEFT(E2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(E2,CHAR(10),CHAR(1),2))-1))`

`=MID(E11,FIND(CHAR(10),E11)+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(E11,CHAR(10),CHAR(1),2))-FIND(CHAR(10),E11)-1)`

`=IF(ISERROR(RIGHT(E14,LEN(E14)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(E14,CHAR(10),"@",(LEN(E14)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E14,CHAR(10),"")))/LEN(CHAR(10)))))),E14,RIGHT(E14,LEN(E14)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(E14,CHAR(10),"@",(LEN(E14)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E14,CHAR(10),"")))/LEN(CHAR(10))))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand all of the line feed characters to spaces the length of the original string then picking up the first, second, last, next-to-last becomes simple maths.

```
'first
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2, CHAR(10), REPT(CHAR(32), LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)))
'second
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2, CHAR(10), REPT(CHAR(32), LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)*1, LEN(A2)))
'last
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2, CHAR(10), REPT(CHAR(32), LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)))
'next-to-last
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2, CHAR(10), REPT(CHAR(32), LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)*(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2, CHAR(10), ""))-1), LEN(A2)))
'second-from-last
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2, CHAR(10), REPT(CHAR(32), LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)*(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2, CHAR(10), ""))-2), LEN(A2)))

'all in sequence when filled down (E3 per supplied image)
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A$2, CHAR(10), REPT(CHAR(32), LEN(A$2))), LEN(A$2)*(ROW(1:1)-1)+1, LEN(A$2)))
```

[image]

Comment: This, sir or madame, is beautiful

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",999)),(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"")))*999-998,999))
```

[image]